# Find cumulative sum values in R / Error: Problem with `mutate()` column

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am working on COVID data for my project. I would like to ask one question.
I selected 10 countries from the dataset. Then I should find a cumulative number of cases for each country, but when I try to do it in pivot_longer format, it does not work. It gives an error like:
"Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Cumulative_cases_Austria`.
i `Cumulative_cases_Austria = cumsum(Selected_countries$Austria)`.
i `Cumulative_cases_Austria` must be size 897 or 1, not 0."
When I try to do it in pivot_wider format, it does not work because the dataset has some NA values.
So, how can I draw line graphs by calculating the cumulative number of cases?

Here is my code:

```
 Selected_countries <- COVID_data %>%
  filter(cases>0) %>%
  replace_na(list(cases=0L)) %>%
  filter(countriesAndTerritories=="France"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Germany"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Spain"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Austria"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Croatia"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Denmark"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Finland"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Greece"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Iceland"|
           countriesAndTerritories=="Italy") %>%
  select(countriesAndTerritories, dateRep,cases) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = countriesAndTerritories, values_from = cases) %>% 
  mutate(Cumulative_cases_Austria = cumsum(Selected_countries$Austria),
         Cumulative_cases_Croatia= cumsum(Selected_countries$Croatia),
         Cumulative_cases_Denmark= cumsum(Selected_countries$Denmark),
         Cumulative_cases_Finland= cumsum(Selected_countries$Finland),
         Cumulative_cases_France= cumsum(Selected_countries$France),
         Cumulative_cases_Germany= cumsum(Selected_countries$Germany),
         Cumulative_cases_Greece= cumsum(Selected_countries$Greece),
         Cumulative_cases_Iceland= cumsum(Selected_countries$Iceland),
         Cumulative_cases_Italy= cumsum(Selected_countries$Italy),
         Cumulative_cases_Spain= cumsum(Selected_countries$Spain)) %>%
  select(c(-Austria,-Croatia,-Denmark,-Finland,-France,-Germany,-Greece,-Iceland,-Italy,-Spain))
```

Our dataset looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOBkg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPSAc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiHQF.png)

Comment: Could you show what does COVID_data look like ?

Comment: Sure, I added the image of the datase.

Comment: @Emre - can you use ``dput(head(data))`` to share you data rather than post images. It's much easier for people to help you if they can reproduce the data themselves. Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: @user438383 I didn't know about the dput() function. It's my first time using Stack overflow so I didn't know how to add the code and its output. Thank you so much. From now on I will do as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should pay attention to your data which seems to have total cases in the first lines for each country (i.e COVID_data) you may have to remove some unwanted rows before further calculations.

A solution could be to replace NA values by 0 after you created the cases per day dataset. So first I would create a function that replaces NA vlaues by zero :

```
na.zero <- function (x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  return(x)
}
```

Then you could perform your cumulative cases code by adding `na.zero()`after the pivot_wider() part. Also remove `Selected_countries$` before each country as `Selected_countries` has not been created :

```
    Selected_countries <- COVID_data %>%
      filter(cases>0) %>%
      replace_na(list(cases=0L)) %>%
      filter(countriesAndTerritories=="France"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Germany"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Spain"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Austria"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Croatia"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Denmark"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Finland"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Greece"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Iceland"|
               countriesAndTerritories=="Italy") %>%
      select(countriesAndTerritories, dateRep,cases) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = countriesAndTerritories, values_from = cases) %>% 
      na.zero(.)%>%
      mutate(Cumulative_cases_Austria = cumsum(Austria),
             Cumulative_cases_Croatia= cumsum(Croatia),
             Cumulative_cases_Denmark= cumsum(Denmark),
             Cumulative_cases_Finland= cumsum(Finland),
             Cumulative_cases_France= cumsum(France),
             Cumulative_cases_Germany= cumsum(Germany),
             Cumulative_cases_Greece= cumsum(Greece),
             Cumulative_cases_Iceland= cumsum(Iceland),
             Cumulative_cases_Italy= cumsum(Italy),
             Cumulative_cases_Spain= cumsum(Spain)) %>%
      select(c(-Austria,-Croatia,-Denmark,-Finland,-France,-Germany,-Greece,-Iceland,-Italy,-Spain))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bastien Ducreux. It works, and I got it.